# Django DRY class based view

Tags: python, django, dry, django-class-based-views

I'm using CBV in my django app and wondering how can I get an instance in my get_context_data AND in my get_initial functions without repeating code.

example :

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):
model = Post

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(VariationCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    blog_pk = self.kwargs.get('product_pk', None)
    blog = None
    if blog_pk:
        try:
            blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_pk)
        except Blog.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    context['blog'] = blog
    return context

def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    blog_pk = self.kwargs.get('product_pk', None)
    blog = None
    if blog_pk:
        try:
            blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_pk)
            return {"blog": blog}
        except Blog.DoesNotExist:
            return {}
```

The goal here is to fetch the blog instance only once

Answer (score 1):

Override the `dispatch` method, and fetch the blog there. Set it as an attribute `self.blog`. Then, you can access the `self.blog` attribute in your `get_context_data` and `get_initial` views.

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # code that fetches the blog and sets self.blog
        return super(PostCreate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
        initial = super(PostCreate, self).get_initial(**kwargs)
        if self.blog is not None:
            initial['blog'] = self.blog
        return initial

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.blog is not None:
            context['blog'] = self.blog
        return context
```

Comment: Ok cool, it is good practice to always use dispatch to create local variables ?

Comment: Sometimes it might be better to override a different method (e.g. `get` or `post`) instead of dispatch, e.g. if you were using a mixin that checked permissions, and the code that creates the local variable uses the logged in user. In your case, I think it's safe to override `dispatch`, and it saves the duplication of calling `self.blog = get_blog()` in the `get` and `post` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class and extend it in your view:

```
CustomClass(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CustomClass, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        blog_pk = self.kwargs.get('product_pk', None)
        blog = None
        if blog_pk:
            try:
                blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_pk)
            except Blog.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        context['product'] = product
        return context

    def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        blog_pk = self.kwargs.get('product_pk', None)
        blog = None
        if blog_pk:
            try:
                blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_pk)
                return {"blog": blog}
            except Blog.DoesNotExist:
                return {}
```

Then in your view:

```
class PostCreate(CreateView, CustomClass):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostCreate, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        # add something else if needed
        return context
```

Comment: The goal of my question is to avoid fetching the blog instance twice

Answer (score 0):

Ok after re-reading the documentation I found the correct way to do this :

1. fetch the blog instance in get_initial and store in in `self.blog`
2. add self.blog to the context in get_context_data

get_initial is ran before get_context_data so do not fetch the blog instance in get_context_data otherwise you'll get an error like I did :

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):
model = Post

def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    blog_pk = self.kwargs.get('product_pk', None)
    self.blog = None
    if blog_pk:
        try:
            self.blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_pk)
            return {"blog": self.blog}
        except Blog.DoesNotExist:
            return {}

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(VariationCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['blog'] = self.blog
    return context
```